# How to get uploaded file name from django id

Tags: python, django

I simply wanted the exact file name which I have uploaded so that I can read the whole file and show content on the HTML page...

```
class newcodes(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    codefile = models.FileField(upload_to ='programs/')//her is my codefile location in models
```

Here is my function for reading text but i can't get name of the uploaded file so i can't read the file

```
def showcode(request,id):
    programs=newcodes.objects.filter(id=id)
    print(programs)
    # f=open('media/')
    return render(request,"Codes.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
programs=newcodes.objects.filter(id=id)
```

This will return the `QuerySet`. You need to `get` instead of `filter`:

```
program=newcodes.objects.get(id=id)
```

This will give newcodes object. From that you can get the uploaded file as :

```
program.codefile.name
```

If filename is along with the directory, simply split the file name like this:

```
import os
os.path.split(program.codefile.name)[-1]
```